# How to store the path to an S3 bucket uploaded file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two models: Organization and Drawing. They have a 1:1 relationship. Drawing contains two variables: `organization_id` and `file_path`.

At signup of a new organization, I have my Rails application automatically copy a standard file for that organization to my S3 bucket. `File_path` in the Drawing model should include the string to the path where the file is stored.

To the organization's controller I have [added](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1K43Z7KXHM5D5/Uploading-Files-to-Amazon-S3) a reference to the method `upload_file`, which I have included in the Drawing model.

Controller:

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params)
  if @organization.save
    Drawing.upload_file(@organization.id)
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Model:

```
def self.upload_file(id)
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
          credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'], ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']),
          region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
          )
  xmlfile = 'app/assets/other/graph.xml'
  key = "uploads/#{id}/xml-#{id}.xml"
  obj = s3.bucket('mybucketname').object(key)
  obj.upload_file(xmlfile)
  Conceptmap.create!(organization_id: id, xml_file: obj.public_url)
end
```

**Question:** My question concerns the correctness of `xml_file: obj.public_url` on the last line. Here I want to save the bucket-path of the saved file. But I wonder if this is the secure way to do this (or should this path be a hash)? How does this work with a carrierwave uploader; is it then automatically hashed? I don't want just anyone to be able to browse to the file and open it.

Comment: As the error suggets, the 'model' variable isn't specified. But my question, what do you want to do with the 'directory' variable? It isn't used at all here.

Comment: Hi LiveNL, see the two bullets at the end of the original post.

Comment: yes, I do see the bullets, but that doesn't answer the 'model' point I made as far as I can see. You're referring to 'model', the variable, but you never set: 'model = something'. That's why you get that error. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're right. I need to set up a relationship between `file_path` in the Drawing model and the S3 bucket. But I don't know how (if you have any suggestions, please let me know). I guess you're right though that even when that relationship is defined, model in the directory line will still not refer to anything (although for a carrierwave uploader it does work). If I comment out the `directory` line, I get the error `No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_size - graph.xml`. The path for `xmlfile = 'other/graph.xml'` seems incorrect.

Comment: I used bye bug in a controller and did this: File.exists?("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/other/test.xml"). Which gives true, maybe you could try such more complete paths. :)

Comment: Tried it and byebug says 'true' to `File.exists?("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/other/graph.xml")` so the file is definitely there. Not sure therefore what causes the error `No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_size - graph.xml`.

Comment: Can't you use that full path, instead of 'other/graph.xml'? To try.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the new insights.